# How to control angularjs form submit action from external code

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to "intercept" a form submission of an angularjs application so that I can validate that a couple of fields have values. If they don't, I will throw an error and stop, but if all is okay then the submission can continue as normal.

The application is a packaged application. One key constraint is that I am not allowed to make any changes (directive templates, js code etc.) to the application code itself in order to prevent issues with future upgrades.

I have been able to achieve most of the customisation requirements using a self contained block of code that is placed as the bottom of the main app.js file of the application. If this block is removed the app will still work as before, just not with my customisations. Therefore, any code I write needs to be within within this block. I have been using jquery.

I have tried using jquery to change the type of the submit button and also to intercept the submit action, but none of these have worked.

Here is the function from my self contained block

```
function createCustomerHandler() {
    $('body').on('DOMNodeInserted.ra', function() {

        if ($('.modal').length && angular.element($(".modal")).scope().state.dataIsLoading != undefined && !angular.element($(".modal")).scope().state.dataIsLoading) {
            $('body').off('DOMNodeInserted.ra');
            console.log("modal is present.");
            var modalScope = angular.element("div[modal-window='modal-window']").scope();
            if (modalScope.person.type != undefined && modalScope.person.type == "person") {
                console.log("a person");
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    modalScope.person.company.name = "";
                    .
                    .
                    REST OF FUNCTION CODE
                    .
                    .

                    $("form").submit(function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        console.log("CREATE CUSTOMER FORM SUBMIT");
                        let form = this;
                        form.submit(); // submit bypassing the jQuery bound event
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    });
};
```

And here is the form from the application that I am attempting to intercept

```
<form name="createCustomerForm" novalidate="" class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-maxlength">
    <div class="create-ticket__header">
        <h3 class="create-ticket__header-title ng-binding">Create Customer</h3>
        <span class="ng-binding">Complete fields and "Save"</span>
    </div>

    <div class="create-ticket__full-width-section smart-recorder__create-customer-outer">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 create-ticket__section">
                <!--First Name-->
                <div class="col-sm-8 smart-recorder__create-customer-col8">
                    <div class="person-profile-form-item">
                        <label class="label_control-wrap">
                            <span class="label__text_required ng-binding required__label" potentially-required-field="" field-name="firstName" entity="person" data-required="(required)">
                                            First Name
                            </span>
                            <div class="create-ticket__item">
                                <input name="firstName" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched" type="text" ng-model="person.firstName" potentially-required-field="" field-name="firstName" entity="person" maxlength="30" auto-focus="" required="" aria-required="true">
                            </div>
                        </label>
                    </div>
            </div>
.
.
Other form fields
.
.
.
And an example of one of the fields I need to check when intercepting the submit
.
.
<div class="dropdown-input full-width ng-isolate-scope" dropdown="" is-open="state.isOpen" selection-items="selections.companies" selected-item="person.company" selection-callback="updateCompany(item)" title-text="Company" label="name" value="name" update-selected-item="true" selection-filter="true" selection-filter-placeholder-text="assignBlade.searchCompany" typeahead-mode="state.tooManyCompanies" typeahead-details="company as company.name for company in getList($viewValue)" typeahead-get-list="getCompaniesByName(name)" potentially-required-field="" entity="person" aria-required="true">
    <button type="button" class="dropdown-input__button dropdown-toggle ng-binding ng-invalid-required" ng-class="{'ng-invalid-required' : !selectedItem &amp;&amp; required}" aria-required="true" id="" ng-disabled="disabledSelection" title="Company Select one" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Select one
    </button>
    <!-- ngIf: !disabledSelection && showClear && selectedItemValue -->
    <input type="text" potentially-required-field="" field-name="" entity="entity" style="display: none;" name="person.company" ng-required="required" ng-model="selectedItem" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-required">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu full-width">
        <!-- ngIf: selectionFilter && !typeaheadMode --><li class="dropdown-item__header ng-binding ng-scope" ng-if="selectionFilter &amp;&amp; !typeaheadMode">Search</li><!-- end ngIf: selectionFilter && !typeaheadMode -->
        <!-- ngIf: selectionFilter && !typeaheadMode --><li class="dropdown-item_search-bar ng-scope" ng-if="selectionFilter &amp;&amp; !typeaheadMode">
            <i class="icon-search dropdown-item_search-icon"></i>
            <input title="Search for a company" prevent-click-event="" class="dropdown-item_search ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" type="text" ng-model="searchFilterText" ng-keyup="handleKeyup($event)" ng-keydown="handleKeydown($event)" placeholder="Search for a company">
        </li><!-- end ngIf: selectionFilter && !typeaheadMode -->
        <!-- ngIf: typeaheadMode -->
        <!-- ngIf: loadingFlag -->
        <!-- ngIf: firstItemEmpty && !typeaheadMode -->
        <!-- ngRepeat: selectionItem in selectionItems | filter : searchFilterText --><li ng-repeat="selectionItem in selectionItems | filter : searchFilterText" class="ng-scope">
            <a class="dropdown-item" ng-click="itemSelected(selectionItem)" ng-keydown="handleKeydown($event)" href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem">
                Calbro Services
            </a>
        </li><!-- end ngRepeat: selectionItem in selectionItems | filter : searchFilterText --><li ng-repeat="selectionItem in selectionItems | filter : searchFilterText" class="ng-scope">
            <a class="dropdown-item" ng-click="itemSelected(selectionItem)" ng-keydown="handleKeydown($event)" href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem">
                Centari Systems
            </a>
        </li><!-- end ngRepeat: selectionItem in selectionItems | filter : searchFilterText --><li ng-repeat="selectionItem in selectionItems | filter : searchFilterText" class="ng-scope">
            <a class="dropdown-item" ng-click="itemSelected(selectionItem)" ng-keydown="handleKeydown($event)" href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem">
                Invention, Inc.
            </a>
        </li><!-- end ngRepeat: selectionItem in selectionItems | filter : searchFilterText -->
    </ul>
</div>
.
.
.
And finnally, the definition of the submit button
.
.
.
<button type="submit" class="btn_primary create-ticket__action-btn ng-binding" ng-disabled="createCustomerForm.$invalid || state.dataIsLoading" ng-click="createPerson()" disabled="disabled">
                Save
</button>
```

Regardless of changing the button type, or using a jquery .submit event, I cannot intercept what happens when the button is clicked and so the createPerson function is called which does a REST call to the backend of the application that then fails due to missing data.

But the application is not coded in such a way that this doesn't produce an error in such a way that this isn't made clear to the user because the missing values are presets in the OOTB code and part of my customisation was to take out these presets and make the user have to select them.

If anyone can see how to do this, it would be really helpful.

Comment: have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Yes, so for example